# Schengen visa application in UK requires confirmed plane tickets

Tags: uk, paperwork, schengen-visas

I am a non-EU national living in the UK and applying for a Schengen visa. I would like to visit Switzerland and applied through TLS Contact - which is the standard way to apply in the UK. Among their list of documents required is

> Copy of transport documentation with applicant’s name as passenger - by
>   plane confirmed booking with airline booking reference number

The TLS center representative confirmed that without a confirmed booking, the file would be considered incomplete. This is also mentioned on the Swiss embassy [website](https://www.eda.admin.ch/dam/countries/countries-content/united-kingdom/en/visa/UK-visit-visa_EN.pdf)

I have applied for Schengen visas before (at Asian embassies) and they only required an itinerary, not confirmed tickets. Any advice on what to do in this case? Book the flights and take the risk or is there a better option?

Comment: Booking fully refundable flights would appear to be the obvious solution. You can always refund and book cheaper tickets after approval.

Comment: @CMaster want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can book fully refundable flights, which are not cheap, and ask for a refund as soon as the visa is in your hands or you have the denial.

Or you can buy a cheap airline ticket or even a bus ticket for the smallest possible amount of money. When you get your visa you can either use it or buy a better ticket or an upgrade.